# Endless loop recording string

Tags: c++, c, string, visual-studio, loops

The code should create a doubly linked list. THen a list of IP adresses should be added to this list with the number of times the unique IP is met. Then the list should be sorted. TO my sorry, the code is cycled somewhere when it's recorded. Highlighted the place in bold (tried to do that:)). 
P.S. I would be pleased if you'll help me with sort method selection. I've already made one, but what would be better to use quicksort or something else?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
struct IP
{
    char b[20];
    int count;
};
struct Node
{
    IP a;

    Node *Next,*Prev;
};
struct List
{
    Node *Head,*Tail;
    int length;
    List():Head(NULL),Tail(NULL){};


};
List* list_new()
{
    return (List *)calloc(1, sizeof(List));
}
void list_delete(List* l)
{
    while (l->Head)
    {
        l->Tail=l->Head->Next;
        free (l->Head);
        l->Head=l->Tail;
    }
    l->length=0;
}
bool push(List* l, IP a)
{
    Node *temp=(Node* ) calloc (1, sizeof(Node));
    temp->Next=NULL;
    temp->a=a;
    if (l->Head!=NULL)
    {
        temp->Prev=l->Tail;
        l->Tail->Next=temp;
        l->Tail=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->Prev=NULL;
        l->Head=l->Tail=temp;
    }
    return 1;
}
bool pop(List*l, IP* x)
{
    (*x)=l->Tail->a;
    l->Tail->Prev->Next=NULL;
    l->Tail=l->Tail->Prev;
    l->length++;
    return 1;
}
bool unshift(List*l, IP a)
{
    Node *temp=(Node* ) calloc (1, sizeof(Node));
    temp->Next=NULL;
    temp->a=a;
    if (l->Head!=NULL)
    {
        temp->Next=l->Head;
        l->Head->Prev=temp;
        l->Head=temp;


    }
    else
    {
        temp->Prev=NULL;
        l->Head=l->Tail=temp;
    }
    return 1;
}
bool shift(List* l, IP* x)
{
    (*x)=l->Head->a;
    l->Head->Next->Prev=NULL;
    l->Head=l->Head->Next;
    return 1;
}
bool reverse (List* l)
{
    Node* temp=l->Head;
    Node* swaps=NULL;
    l->Tail=l->Head;
    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        swaps=temp->Prev;
        temp->Prev=temp->Next;
        temp->Next=swaps;
        temp=temp->Prev;
    }
    if (swaps != NULL) l->Head = swaps->Prev;
    return 1;
}
void sort (List* l)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<l->length; ++i) {
        Node* compared = l->Head;
        while (compared->Next != NULL) {
            if (compared->Next->a.count > compared->a.count) {
                IP t = compared->Next->a;
                compared->Next->a = compared->a;
                compared->a = t;
            }
            compared = compared->Next;
        }
    }
}
void Show(List* l)
{
    int i;

    Node* temp=l->Head;
    while (temp!=NULL)
    {

        cout<<temp->a.b<<" "<<temp->a.count<<"\n";
        temp=temp->Next;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

int main ()
{
    int i;
    char strbuf[1000],chTemp;
    IP ipTemp;
    bool met;
    system("CLS");

    List* l = list_new();

    FILE* foo;
    errno_t err;
    err=fopen_s(&foo,"input.txt","r");
    if( err == 0 )
    {
        printf( "The file 'input.txt' was opened\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The file 'input.txt' was not opened\n" );
    }
    while (!feof(foo))
    {

        fgets(strbuf,1000,foo);
        fclose(foo);
        for (i=0;i++;i<20)
            if (strbuf[i]==' ') {strncpy_s( ipTemp.b,strbuf, i);break;}

        Node* cur = l->Head;
        met=0;
        while (cur!=NULL)
        {
            if (cur->a.b == ipTemp.b)
            {
                met=1;
                cur->a.count++;
                break;
            }
            cur=cur->Next;
        }
        if (met==0)
        {
            push(l,ipTemp);
            l->Tail->a.count++;
        }
    }

    sort(l);
    Show(l);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: It's always so painful for eyes to see a mix of C and C++

Comment: Apart from class constructors (which are never fired because you `calloc()` rather than `new`), there is no significant usage of the C++ programming language in this **at all**. If you want a sorted linked list of string, use `std::list<std::string>` and `std::list::sort` and be done with it. If this is for a C++ programming class, you're likely not going to get anything close to a respectable grade. The sort algorithm is the least of your worries. Get the list, the loader, and the management down *first*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code had a cleaner indentation, you would maybe realize that the logic is wrong:

```
while (!feof(foo))
{
    fgets(strbuf,1000,foo);     // <-- what if fgets hits EOF or error occurs?
    fclose(foo);                // <-- why?
    for (i = 0; i++; i < 20)    // <-- i++ is always true ~> infinite loop
        ....
    ...
}
```

should be (assuming you want to write code in C):

```
while (fgets(strbuf, 1000, foo))
{
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        ....
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 and you can easily replicate the `// <-- why?` comment on the `while` expression and about 80% of the rest of the code as well. Not knowing the input format is decidedly inconvenient, but obviously any line without a space in the first 20 chars (whether that was how many was read or not) is ignored. That may be intentional, but its very hard to tell. I would upvote this answer again if I could just for the effort to decipher meaning where there  is little-to-none.

Answer (score 1):

`for (i=0;i++;i<20)` should be `for (i=0;i<20;i++)`